# arrays structure when loading data into iphone

Tags: iphone, model-view-controller, ios4, nsmutablearray

i've been into iphone programming for a couple of weeks now, and i've managed to create my first sqlite driven database.

for my first basic application, i have 2 tables (with a one-many relationship): brands, products

```
brands (code, brandname)
products (code, brandcode, productname, price, ...)
```

as for my sample data:

```
* brands:
1 apple
2 hp
*products:
1 1 Macbookpro
2 1 iphone
3 1 ipad2
4 2 hpnotebook
```

and i have 2 nib files: 1 with a tableviews showing the list of brands, and one having some outlets to show brand information and a tableview to show the corresponding products.

at first i've created 2 nsmutablearrays in the application delegate that i load during the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

however, there's no way to know the data in the cell for the cellForRowAtIndexPath function when i'm loading the second tableview because my array of products has them all.. and i wouldn't know what's the second product that matches the criteria of brandcode=1

so i changed my brand class structure so that it contains an nsmutablearray of products.
and while loading products i add them each to the nsmutablearray of the parent brand.

performance-wise: was what i did correct? or are there any better ways to filter my products table.

i appreciate your help and time

cheers,

Comment: You mention this is an SQLite project. Are you using CoreData to access, or another SQL Library? Either way, you can make a query based upon the table you are loading:  "SELECT name FROM Brands" and then "SELECT name FROM Products WHERE brand = 'The one the user just selected".  (This is Psuedo code to depict my point, if this seems like something you want more info on, I can make it accurate and post as an answer.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would create two Classes (Brand and Product). The Brand class contains an MutArray with Product-instances. The ViewController or AppDelegate holds an MutArray of Brands. You have to pass information from the first TableView to the second tableview.

You have two possibilities:

1: On click on a brand `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` you get the selected obj using: `product = [brands objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` and pass that product to the second viewController (eg via a new `initWithProduct:`) which then present data of that product.

2: On click on a brand: pass just the index/primaryKey of that brand and the second ViewController fetches all Products of that key from the db itself.

Comment: hey thomas, i've already did the project and it's working! i already used the first scenario that u proposed. and i actually thought about the second scenario (the second view controller will fetch the data from the db itself...) -- my question is: is this the best way to do it?? or fetching it from the database is a better approach?

Comment: it depends. If your db is a huge monster (data-size) then it will be better to fetch only the data you need (approach 2) according to memory-need. If your db is relatively small (a few MB) then it will be better to fetch all data first (approach 1) according to speed during app-use after first-fetch

Answer (score 1):

You could create an instance variable in the .h file of the brand details view that is of `NSMutableArray` type. When you catch the event for when a user wants to see the brands you then attach the correct array of products to that table view controller.

When the user clicks (`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath`) on a brand in the first table view do something like this:

```
MyTableView *tableView = [[MyTableView alloc] init];
tableView.myNSMutableArrayforABrand = arrayWithProductData;
[self.view addSubview:tableView]
[tableView release];
```

This way you attach the data from the first table view to the second.

Comment: hey jeroen, thanks for ur quick reply... and honestly.. nice piece of code. but my project is already functioning properly, i just want to know if it's a good practice to put an array of products in a brand class...

Comment: Actually it is best to keep things loosely coupled, specially when considering the disadvantages (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_science)#Disadvantages). To achieve that you would ultimately create one class for a product, one for the brand and another collection class that kept the relationship of those sorted in an appropriate data structure. On the other hand that takes more time and a good programmer needs to chose the appropriate amount of time (based on the complexcity,size of a project) to spend on these things. Best :) !

Comment: Also if I answered your questions please consider checking this as correct.